# How to use createTemplate in AdminCustomersController in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop

I create a custom module in which I want to add new option to client list. By default the user can use options: view, edit or delete. I want to add check option. For this test I modify the main controller AdminCustomersControllerCore without override.

In \controllers\admin\AdminCustomersController.php

```
public function displayEraseLink($token = null, $id, $name = null) {
        $tpl = $this->createTemplate(_PS_MODULE_DIR_ . $this->module->name.'/views/templates/admin/list_action_erase.tpl');
        $tpl->assign(array(
            'confirm' => $this->l('Erase all client data') . $name,
            'action' => $this->l('Erase'),
            'id' => $id,
        ));
        return $tpl->fetch();
    }
```

I want to load list_action_erase.tpl which is location in modules\my_module\views\templates\admin\list_action_erase.tpl. In server log I see:

Unable to load template file '/home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html/admin3640wjafn/themes/default/template//home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html/modules//views/templates/admin/list_action_erase.tpl

How to load view from another location ?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
$tpl = $this->createTemplate(_PS_MODULE_DIR_ . $this->module->name.'/views/templates/admin/list_action_erase.tpl');
```

use

```
$tpl = $this->context->smarty->createTemplate(_PS_MODULE_DIR_ . $this->module->name.'/views/templates/admin/list_action_erase.tpl');
```

`$this->createTemplate()` is a wrapper for `$this->context->smarty->createTemplate()` in `AdminController` which will look for a template relative to folder `/adminfolder/themes/default/template/`.

Using `$this->context->smarty->createTemplate()` itself you can specify absolute path to your template.